# duplicate entry error in unique column with charser utf8_czech_ci

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table with charset: utf8_czech_ci. And I have column 'name' with unique key.
If I insert value 'zelená' and 'zelena', a I get error Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
How can i repair it?

Comment: What is the character sets and collation of the column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: collaction of column is too utf8_czech_ci and sets is any char (with accents too)